# Handling IRI in Django

Tags: python, django, url, unicode

The Django documentation has a [nice section] on handling strings with non-ASCII data in URLs. In particular, it presents the following example on how to transform Unicode strings for use in URLs:

```
>>> urlquote(u'Paris & Orléans')
u'Paris%20%26%20Orl%C3%A9ans'
>>> iri_to_uri(u'/favorites/François/%s' % urlquote(u'Paris & Orléans'))
'/favorites/Fran%C3%A7ois/Paris%20%26%20Orl%C3%A9ans'
```

However, there seems to be no indication on how to perform the reverse transformation!

Assuming that my application receives the URL `/favorites/Fran%C3%A7ois/Paris%20%26%20Orl%C3%A9ans`, how do I map that back to `/favorites/François/` and `Paris & Orléans`?

There is no `django.utils.encoding.uri_to_iri` function to complement `django.utils.encoding.iri_to_uri` and there is no `django.utils.http.urlunquote` to complement `django.utils.http.urlquote()`!

**Note**:

If this helps at all, I'm using Django 1.2 over

- Python 2.5, Debian Linux 32-bit
- Python 2.6, Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `urllib.unquote()` should work just fine in this case:

```
>>> urllib.unquote('/favorites/Fran%C3%A7ois/Paris%20%26%20Orl%C3%A9ans')
'/favorites/Fran\xc3\xa7ois/Paris & Orl\xc3\xa9ans'
```

Comment: Whoa, that's weird! `urllib.quote()` doesn't handle unicode data, but `urllib.unquote` handles UTF-8 just fine! It works!

Comment: Not quite. `urllib.unquote()` returns a bytestring, and it is up to you to decode it from UTF-8. `urllib.quote()` expects a bytestring too, it handles unicode just fine if you encode the unicode string to UTF-8 first.

Comment: Example: `urllib.quote(u'ąčę'.encode('utf8')) => '%C3%A0%C3%A8%C3%A6'`

Comment: Yeah, that's the first thing I did `urllib.unquote(x).decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `urllib.unquote` does this for you:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> print urllib.unquote('/favorites/Fran%C3%A7ois/Paris%20%26%20Orl%C3%A9ans')
/favorites/François/Paris & Orléans
```